# Update Table Based Off Temporary Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, temp

In a postrgres system, I have created a temporary table that holds a foreign key value to another table. I am hoping to update another table with information from that temporary table based on the foreign key value in the table I want to update.

My thought was to use an update query such as:

`update  playerdata set "slotID"=temp1."gameID" from temp1 where playerdata."PlayerID"=playerdata."PlayerID";`

However when I do this update, I get the same gameID for every slotID in the table when they should be different based off of playerID.

For example if temp holds:

```
playerid gameID
1         10
2         11
```

the result of the player data table update is:

```
playerid     slotID
1             10
2             10
```

and I want the result to be:

```
playerid     slotID
1             10
2             11
```

I have also worked with a join statement with the temporary table and it works as expected, the gameID's are with their corresponding playerID. 
`select w."PlayerID", t."gameID" from playerdata as w, temp1 as t where t."PlayerID" = w."PlayerID";`

Is there a way to update the player data table's slotid based off the corresponding temporary playerID and gameID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `join` condition is incorrect in the first query:

```
update playerdata
    set "slotID"=temp1."gameID"
    from temp1
    where playerdata."PlayerID" = temp1."PlayerID";
----------------------------------^
```

Comment: wow, I've literally been scratching my head over this for the past hour. Sometimes all it takes is a fresh pair of eyes. Thanks so much!